# How to avoid login multiple times in Facebbok login by using in SDK 3.01

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am using latest faceboook android SDK 3.01 in my application. by using this i am able to share on my facebook wall well it's working fine, but login it's asking login on every time when i want to share something on facebbok. When i login into facebook and then closing the application coming back to app (open again) and try then try to sharing anything on facebook again it's asking login. In the previous SDK i was commented some code in facebbok class , but now that code not available in facebook class.  I am trying like this

```
Utility.mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);         
Utility.mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(Utility.mFacebook);
SessionStore.restore(Utility.mFacebook, this);
boolean see =  Utility.isActive();      
if(!Utility.mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
   Utility.mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE, new LoginDialogListener());
} else {            
   postToWall();
}
```

How to avoid login multiple times ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have diabled the singleSignOn feature altogether.

Find method like authorize(..)  and enable singleSignOn from there.

like..

```
public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
            final DialogListener listener) {
        authorize(activity, permissions, DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE/*FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH*/, listener);//FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH-- To disable singleSignOnStarted. 
    }
```

Comment: I didn't disable any code in facebook class, all are in enable state. i am using code as it is downloaded from facebook site.

Answer (score 0):

You are still using older SDK code. Newer facebook android sdk 3.0 doesnt recommend to use `Facebook()`. Those are deprecated. I strongly suggest you to take a look at this sample and see the code.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample

Comment: i want to implement with out using login button, how to implement like this.and i don't want sso. How to disable SSO.